# What is the state in $stateprovider refers to?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to the Ionic and AngularJS. 
Can anybody provide me a Tutorial which clearly explains the syntax of $stateprovider like what is .state refers to and what is  its syntax.

In the ionic sliding menu template

```
.state('app.single', {
url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
    controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
  }
```

I didn't understood what that app.single refers.

Can anybody please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

In short, the state is the current state of the SPA if you consider it like a state machine.

```
.state( 'app.single', { // app is the parent state, single is  a child state. 
         url: '/playlists/:playlistId', // This is telling the router what to display as 
                                        // the url in the browser window 
                                        // i.e. www.site.com/playlists/:playlistId
         views: { // Now we will assign the content of the various views
             'menuContent': { templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html', 
                                        // This is telling the router where to find the 
                                        // HTML which it will insert into the menuContent
                                        // view. In essence this is what defines this
                                        // particular state
                              controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'} // This is telling the router
                                        // what controller to use for the content that was
                                        // inserted into menuContent
         }
      )
```